# Disable gesture recognizer iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, multi-touch, gesture-recognition

i'm developing a application for gestures recognizer for iPad and i want to disable the default gesture recognizer of the iOS. When i ask a way do disable the gestures recognizer is using my own application, so i need a way using some functions of the api and not using the settings way.

Comment: I think you should reopen/edit this question. Although I doubt whether it is possible to disable these, the gestures are now officially part of iOS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The four- and five- finger gestures are not officially part of iOS, and may never be.

Though it would be best to figure out an alternative, you should be able to use these gestures for now and not fear conflicts (save on the iPads of developers who have specifically turned on this feature, whose users know that said features may conflict with apps.)

Answer (score 4):

I don't completely understand your question.

You can add UIGestureRecognizer to objects. You can also remove them.

```
- (void)removeTarget:(id)target action:(SEL)action
```

For example:

```
  [imageView addGestureRecognizer:singleTap];
  [imageView removeGestureRecognizer:singleTap];
```

Comment: But if you want to remove the native gesture of iOS, for example the gesture with 5 fingers that return to the menu

Comment: You can't. The OS' global behaviour is not under your control.

Answer (score 0):

One alterative is to change your design to avoid 4-5 finger swipe. From what i know, the 4-5 gesture setting is for end-users to return home screen/open up multitasking bar and you can't do anything about it till Apple releases it for developer, right now it's still on the stage of experimenting for end users.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a UITapGesture and set the number of touches in the Attribute Inspector if you want multiple touches. Doesn't this do what you want?

Answer (score 0):

when you go to gestures in the assistive touch menu, to disable it you swipe to the right like you would to delete a song or a note.