# How does UILongPressRecognizer work?

Tags: ios, objective-c, mkmapview, uigesturerecognizer

If you start pressing the screen, but move the finger because `minimumPressDuration` ellapses, the gesture gets cancelled and your movement gets forwared to the view. If `minimumPressDuration` is reached, it doesn't matter how much you move the finger. I want to avoid this and always cancel my gesture if the finger movement is bigger than `allowableMovement`.

I've seen [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9688139/uilongpressgesturerecognizer-stop-handle-without-stop-touching), but that solution isn't working for me.

I've tried subclassing `UILongPressureGestureRecognizer`, and set the state to failed or cancelled when my requirement is met, but doesn't seem to work, I guess cancelling it isn't enough and have to forward the events myself? How should I do this? My intention is to use it together with `MKMapView`. I'm getting really frustrated with this, I've tried it for two days.

Comment: I believe MKMapView has a delegate method for Map View Visible Region Changed: -(void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView regionWillChangeAnimated:(BOOL)animated { ... } have you tried cancelling your long press gesture in that method ?

Comment: The main problem is that if minimumPressDuration ellapses, my finger movement isn't forwared to MKMapView, and therefore my región won't change.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one :

```
UILongPressGestureRecognizer *longpress = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(LongPress_action:)];
longpress.minimumPressDuration = 2.0; //seconds
longpress.delegate = self;
[yourview addGestureRecognizer:longpress]; // where you want to add
```

Call this method :

```
- (void)LongPress_action:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer*)gesture
{
    if ( gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded ) 
    {
       NSLog(@"Long Press");
    }
}
```

Comment: My long press gesture is attached and working, what I want to achieve is cancelling the gesture whenever the user moves the finger >  allowableMovement, not only before the gesture has been detected.

Comment: when you moved your finger means in touchMoved method you have to cancel the UILongPressGestureRecognizer.

Comment: Already tried that in my subclass, but I either did it wrong, or it doesn't work. Any code snippet?