# UIButton: Pressed Quickly

Tags: objective-c, animation, uibutton

If I press & hold a UIButton, the pressed button is rendered; if I press quickly, the UIButton segues to its targeted ViewController. How do I achieve the press & hold effect on a button pressed quickly in Objective-C?

Button Pressed Quickly:

[image]

Button Pressed & Held:

[image: Button Pressed & Held]

Comment: Would a `UILongPressRecognizer` and custom code for modifying the appearance work?

Comment: Thanks, @ILikeTau. Could you elaborate in a post? What custom code do you have in mind?

Comment: You button, is it a subview to anything? is it a subview to a `UIScrollView`?

Comment: Thanks, @tnylee... No, it is not ;) It is a button in a cell for UITableView. I just want to enable the "pressed" effect long enough to give the user the right feel.

Comment: The reason our button is delayed to highlight is because the UIScrollView in your UITableView. Have a look at this question and answers http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19256996/uibutton-not-showing-highlight-on-tap-in-ios7/26049216#26049216 Good luck!

Comment: [Here's](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9688139/uilongpressgesturerecognizer-stop-handle-without-stop-touching) an example. Whenever the long press is recognized just highlight the button.

Answer (score 0):

just use

```
myButton.highlighted = Yes
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
  [myButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:<Normal - Image>] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
  [myButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:<Highlight - Image>] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
```